# Fusión de etiquetas python

Tags: discusión, etiquetas, sinónimos-de-etiquetas

En la actualidad tenemos tres etiquetas para python: `python`, `python-2.7` y `python-3.x`. La idea era tener separadas las preguntas *genéricas* sobre python de las que eran específicas de una de las dos versiones más usadas.

Hoy en día, se considera que la versión 3.5 de python es la versión principal de este lenguaje, siendo la 2.7 una versión *transitoria* para facilitar la migración de todo desarrollo con python2 a la nueva versión. En estos momentos, no parece tener sentido una etiqueta propia para `python-3.x`.

Propongo que la etiqueta `python` sea la etiqueta *"mainstream"* de python, asociada a la versión 3.x, y dejar `python-2.7` para preguntas relacionadas con versiones anteriores de python. Con ello, la etiqueta `python-3.x` desaparecería, cuyas preguntas habría que asociarles la etiqueta `python` en el caso de que no la tuvieran.

Comment: Apoyo la moción.

Comment: Hola ChemaCortes. No conozco mucho respecto a python excepto que las diferencias entre la versión 2 y 3 son notables empezando por `print 'hola'` y `print('hola')`. Si los miembros de la comunidad con bastante conocimiento sobre python como `@Cesar`, `@JavierCardenas` y otros (según [puntuación en respuestas a etiqueta python](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/python/info)) lo consideran, entonces veré por realizar dicho cambio.

Comment: Si, totalmente de acuerdo. Pienso que es una forma de apoyar una mayor adopción de python 3.x

Comment: Luiggi, está claro que hay diferencias entre las dos versiones. Pero únicamente la versión 3 se sigue desarrollando oficialmente, quedando la 2.7 como última versión de la rama 2. Cuando surge algún problema serio, como ocurrió con la vulnerabilidad de las librerías SSL, se solucionó primero en la librería estándar de python3 y fue luego cuando se pasó (*backport*) a python 2.7. El resto de versiones anteriores a la 2.7 siguen con esta vulnerabilidad y se deben apañar con módulos no-oficiales. Adicionalmente, python3 acaba de dar un gran salto con la nueva sintáxis para programación asíncrona.

Comment: @ChemaCortes Entiendo tu idea y sí estoy de acuerdo en que la versión 3 tiene más desarrollo por parte de la versión 2. De todas maneras, necesito ver más apoyo por parte de la comunidad misma sobre esta pregunta para realizar los cambios que sugieres. Nunca se sabe si surgen ideas en base a la idea que propones que pueden resultar también interesantes :). Nota personal: yo apoyo tu moción.

Comment: No estoy de acuerdo, asumes que no habrá una version 4. Las etiquetas con version son para hacer preguntas especificas sobre dicha version, como el ejemplo citado por Luiggi, cualquier otra pregunta debe ir con la etiqueta de la version genérica del lenguaje. Según esta lógica, no tiene sentido una etiqueta java8, c#6, javascript6, etc... etc.. y si lo tiene

Comment: Cuando python esté en versión 4, entonces la etiqueta `python` será para python4 y habrá que crear una nueva para python3. Por comparar, no tienen etiquetas específicas php, mysql, ni javascript (aunque hay una de `ecmascript-2015`). En java hay etiquetas específicas para `java8` y `java9`, aunque igual debería haberlas para el resto de versiones. Mi propuesta es escoger el modelo más sencillo de etiquetado, pero es tan sólo una opinión.

Comment: @ChemaCortes las hay y reciben apoyo de la comunidad. Por ello, como vuelvo a comentar, si veo que la comunidad aquí apoya lo que tú indicas, entonces se crearán dichas etiquetas.

Comment: Voto en contra de convertir [tag:python] en un acceso directo al Python más de moda. Veo mucho más práctico, útil y esclarecedor usar Python para todas y luego otra etiqueta con la versión exacta. Por algo nos dejan usar tantas etiquetas y no una solamente :)

Comment: Así es como se quedó, no hace falta votar más. Pero no diría que python3 sea una *"moda"*. Es la versión actual en desarrollo, mientras que python 2.7 llegó a su *final de camino*.

Comment: Chema: pero convendrás conmigo que Python 2.7 sigue utilizándose de forma muy extensa, no ha sido un cambio de versión al uso en el que todo el mundo migra a la nueva.

Comment: No voy a volver a discutir el tema, porque no es un problema de popularidad. Si tienes un problema en python 2.7 que está resuelto en python 3, esa es la respuesta, porque no habrá más cambios en python 2.7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No veo interés en esta propuesta, por lo que considero que será mejor que las cosas sigan como están. Todo aquél que haga preguntas sobre [python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) debería especificar siempre la versión específica con la etiqueta correspondiente, [python-2.7](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-2.7) o [python-3.x](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x).

Answer (score 1):

En la comunidad de python, los temas relacionados con `python 2` vs `python 3` siempre causan polémica...

De hecho ya van 7 años desde el lanzamiento de `python 3` y es la hora y aún existen inconvenientes para que la comunidad lo acepte como la versión principal de este lenguaje. Esto principalmente por la incompatibilidad con la versión 2.x. Fue un cambio brusco que a muchos no gusto para nada, debido a que simplemente el trabajo de migrar mi código de `python 2` a `python 3` (o mantener ambas versiones) no valía la pena el esfuerzo comparado con los beneficios que ofrecía en su momento de lanzamiento.

En otras palabras el pensamiento general era: *para que voy a cambiar? si lo que tengo hasta ahora me funciona bien y el esfuerzo de cambiar no me agrega nada valioso para mi*. La gente se "rebeldizo" y dejo a un lado la imposición de `python 3`, incluso proponiendo crear `python 2.8` haciendo que la adopción de esta versión fuera muy lenta.

Creo que la comunidad hubiera preferido que el cambio fuera gradual; sin embargo, ya llegamos a un punto donde la mayoría de las librerías populares, django o numpy por ejemplo (ver [python wall of superpowers](https://python3wos.appspot.com/)), ya son compatibles con `python 3` y para la gente que esta aprendiendo a programar, que es uno de los nichos de python, es preferible que empiecen sus proyectos con `python 3`.

Por esta razón desde StackOverflow en español podemos apoyar a que python 3 termine por fin ese letargo, ya que ahora si existen motivos de peso para hacer la transición en los usuarios actuales, y los usuarios nuevos no tienen necesidad de usar la versión vieja.

Comment: En mi propuesta no pretendía reavivar polémicas entre python2 y python3. Lo que no veo sentido es a tener una etiqueta `python` si luego no se especifica también si es `python-2.7` ó `python-3.x`. Hasta ahora, era factible pasar de python 2.7 a python3; en estos momentos, la evolución de python3 ha llegando al punto de que todo código anterior se tendrá que reprogramar o descartar. No es cosa de obligar a nadie a cambiar (para ello estará la etiqueta `python-2.7`), pero el lenguaje python está oficialmente en versión 3 y es lo que debería asumirse por defecto.