# Fusión etiquetas Python (y van 3)

Tags: discusión, etiquetas, sinónimos-de-etiquetas, desambiguación-etiquetas

Sé que no es la primera vez que se discute esto, pero visto que hace 3 años de la última vez y que python-2 ha dejado ya de tener soporte excepto "CVE"s, quisiera volver a retomar ese debate.

¿No es mejor dejar la etiqueta [python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) y dejar la de [python-2.x](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-2.x) para usuarios con esa necesidad exclusiva?

Acabo de mirar la comparación entre el uso actual de las etiquetas y las de python-2.x casi se mantiene estable mientras que [python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) y [python-3.x](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x) suben en popularidad.

Desde mi punto de vista actual la gran mayoría de preguntas sobre Python son de aprendices y ellos casi en exclusiva empiezan con Python 3.

[image: Gráfica de uso de etiquetas python]

¿Qué os parece? ¿Sería posible quizás advertir a los nuevos usuarios de que usen python de forma general y python-2.x cuando sea algo especifico de esa versión?

Discusiones anteriores:

- [Fusión de etiquetas python](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/518/fusi%C3%B3n-de-etiquetas-python)
- [Etiquetas con versiones específicas de python](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/etiquetas-con-versiones-espec%C3%ADficas-de-python)
- [Fusionar python-3.x con python (otra vez)](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2890/fusionar-python-3-x-con-python-otra-vez)

Comment: _si no es mejor dejar la etiqueta Python y dejar la de python-2.x para usuarios con esa necesidad exclusiva puesto que acabo de mirar la comparación entre el uso actual de las etiquetas y las de python-2.x casi se mantiene estable_ no entiendo esta frase. También sería bueno que si mencionar discusiones previas (que las hubo) las enlaces, para tener contexto.

Comment: La etiqueta clave cuando se pregunta sobre Python es... [tag:python]. Si existe algún matiz que hace importante indicar la versión, se le añade [tag:python-3.x] o lo que sea. Esto se indica en [la wiki de la etiqueta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/python/info) y creo que es bastante claro y fácil.

Comment: Quería decir que mirando la grafica, el uso de las etiquetas de python-2 se mantiene más o menos constante en el tiempo y que las etiquetas python y python-3 han aumentado mucho más en popularidad, sobre todo "python" a secas. Tienes razon con los enlaces a las anteriores discusiones, ahora lo cambio

Comment: Entiendo el propósito de distinguir entre versiones, pero mi pregunta era si seguía siendo necesario a día de hoy la existencia entre "python" y "python-3.x" porque me parece que comienza a ser redundante.

Comment: Entiendo el debate, pero no veo el problema: si una pregunta no usa nada específico, se asume que es de Python 3 y se etiqueta solamente con [tag:python]. Imaginemos que juntamos [tag:python-3.x] y [tag:python], ¿qué ocurrirá cuando tengamos Python 4?

Comment: Entiendo que el problema de distinguir entre versiones radica en la rotura de compatibilidad entre la versión 2 y la 3 por forzosa necesidad (y criterio de Guido) y no por un salto numérico. Pienso que bastante problemas ha traído ese cambio como para que vuelva a ocurrir en un futuro cercano con la versión 4. Pero comprendo y comparto tu duda. La idea era hacerlo más fácil para los nuevos usuarios que puedan tener dudas a la hora de elegir etiqueta (que yo también tuve).

Comment: En Angular tenemos un problema similar, con la diferencia de que cada 6 meses hay una nueva versión. Originalmente se añadieron angular2 y angular4 como sinónimos de [tag:angular] (no hubo versión 3), pero se ha dejado de hacer para el resto de versiones (y ya vamos por angular10) porque es importante a menudo saber sobre qué versión hablamos por pequeñas incompatibilidades y cambios que van surgiendo

Comment: Sí, la transición de Python 3 a 4 parece que será más suave (dicen que irá tras la 3.9, independientemente de que haya incompatibilidades). Yo lo que he detectado es que mucha gente etiqueta solamente con [tag:python-3.x], lo que hace más difícil revisar la etiqueta, pese a que [hay una advertencia sobre las preguntas con Python*](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3860/83).

Comment: Yo no veo la necesidad de fusionar o eliminar etiquetas ya que las versiones indican que se debe tomar en cuenta las diferencias(sintaxis, librerías disponibles, etc). Que python2 no tenga soporte no implica que no sea utilizado, muchas veces por cuestiones de estabilidad se siga manteniendo SW antiguo pero estable.

Comment: Personalmente, creo que python debe quedar como etiqueta generica y usar solo la versión en caso de que sea relevante, como bien dice @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar'

Comment: Me surgen unas preguntas y agradecería que alguien me las respondiera: *¿Por qué existen las etiquetas ["python-2.7"](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-2.7) y ["python-2.x"](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-2.x)?* *¿Por qué Python 2.7 no se incluye dentro de Python 2.x?* Entiendo que hay que mantener etiquetas para versiones en especifico, pero tanto en la versión 2.5, 2.6 y 2.7, `print` sigue sin ser una función y `map()` sigue devolviendo listas.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Fusionar python-3.x con python (otra vez)](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2890/fusionar-python-3-x-con-python-otra-vez)

Answer (score 1):

> ¿Por qué existen las etiquetas "python-2.7" y "python-2.x"? ¿Por qué Python 2.7 no se incluye dentro de Python 2.x?

**Si verificamos las etiquetas:**

> Python 2.7 es la última versión de la serie 2.x. Incorpora algunas características que han sido introducidas en Python 3 hasta el 1 de enero de 2020, fecha a partir de la cuál queda oficialmente fuera de mantenimiento. Usa la etiqueta más general, [python], siempre, y no utilices [python-2.7] si tu pregunta no es específica de la versión. Si utilizas algún framework también indícalo con [flask], [django] o lo que sea. [Link](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-2.7)

> Para temas relacionados al desarrollo en Python, versión 2.x. Utilizar esta etiqueta sólo para preguntas específicas de esta versión. [Link](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-2.x)

Veremos que la Característica principal es que cada `Etiqueta` esta orientada a un propósito en especial: la búsqueda de respuesta dentro de una version especifica de Python; esto ocurre si se emplean correctamente las etiquetas.

#### Por ejemplo:

Python en la version `2.7` incluye cosas que no están en las versiones `2.x` anteriores: si mi pregunta esta dirigida a cualquiera version debo usar la Etiqueta `2.x`; si mi pregunta va dirigida a algo que se agrego en la version `2.7` es esta la etiqueta que debo usar.

#### Lo mismo esta pasando cuando se hacen preguntas con la Etiqueta de `php`:

Tenemos `php`, `php5`, `php7`.

**En resumen:** es conveniente tener estas etiquetas separadas por facilidad de búsquedas y estadísticas; inconveniente que los nuevos no sepan usarlas; si no existieran estas etiquetas, la persona debería estar colocando la version con la que trabaja y su ambiente de desarrollo y producción, lo cual no ayudaría en las búsquedas de posibles respuesta.

También me imagino que hay otros argumentos que pueden ser justificados por un moderador o administrador.